# Transport from Bucharest to Cluj-Napoca

Tags: air-travel, trains, bookings, buses, train-stations

How can i find information about the official bus/train prices from Bucharest to Cluj-Napoca?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Grüezi Nijat

Trains are through [CFR](https://www.cfrcalatori.ro/en) | 9.5 Hours | $17 - $26 USD

Buses are through [Fany](https://www.fany.ro/) | 9 Hours | $17 - $26 USD

Flights are through [Blue Air](https://www.blueairweb.com/) | 1 Hour | $60 USD

[Rome2Rio](https://www.rome2rio.com/map/Bucharest/Cluj-Napoca) is a helpful website too!

Hope this helps!